# Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed:
                         
   Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///home/builder/hotbuilder/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4564:12

Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///home/builder/hotbuilder/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4564:12

Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///home/builder/hotbuilder/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4564:12
```

The problem occurs in the navigator, but I don't know why.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shoppingapp/screens/components/categories.dart';
import 'package:shoppingapp/model/product.dart';
import 'package:shoppingapp/screens/components/item_card.dart';
import 'package:shoppingapp/screens/details/details_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  final Product product;

  const Body({Key key, this.product}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
          child: Text(
            "Women",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ), //text
        ), //padding
        Categories(),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            child: GridView.builder(
                itemCount: products.length,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 20,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                  childAspectRatio: 0.75,
                ), //silvergrid
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => ItemCard(
                      product: products[index],
                      press: () => Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => DetailsScreen(
                              product: products[index],
                            ), //detailscreen
                          )), //materialpageroute
                    )), //item card//gridview
          ), //padding
        ), //expanded
      ], //widget
    ); //column
  }
}
```

My full error is

```
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
  Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey#7e8f8]
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
  ItemCard

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

The following assertion was thrown building ItemCard(dirty):

setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the

process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase

only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework

builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built.

Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.

The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:

  Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey#7e8f8]

The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:

  ItemCard


The relevant error-causing widget was:

  ItemCard

  /lib/screens/components/body.dart:37:50


When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

dart:sdk_internal 5348:11                                            throw_

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4217:11                  

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4231:14                  markNeedsBuild

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 1108:5                   setState

packages/flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart 436:5                      rearrange

packages/flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart 4065:16                  [_flushHistoryUpdates]

packages/flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart 4573:5                   [_pushEntry]

packages/flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart 4480:5                   push

packages/flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart 2130:32                  push

packages/shoppingapp/screens/components/body.dart 39:46              

dart:sdk_internal 5558:16                                            _checkAndCall

dart:sdk_internal 5601:17                                            callMethod

dart:sdk_internal 5604:17                                            dsend

packages/shoppingapp/screens/components/item_card.dart 12:19         build

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4648:28                  build

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4574:15                  performRebuild

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4267:5                   rebuild

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4553:5                   [_firstBuild]

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4548:5                   mount

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3611:13                  inflateWidget

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3363:18                  updateChild

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6083:14                  mount

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3611:13                  inflateWidget

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3363:18                  updateChild

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6083:14                  mount

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3611:13                  inflateWidget

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3363:18                  updateChild

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4599:16                  performRebuild

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4267:5                   rebuild

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4553:5                   [_firstBuild]

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4548:5                   mount

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3611:13                  inflateWidget

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3363:18                  updateChild

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4599:16                  performRebuild

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4267:5                   rebuild

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4553:5                   [_firstBuild]

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4548:5                   mount

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3611:13                  inflateWidget

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3363:18                  updateChild

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4599:16                  performRebuild

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4746:11                  performRebuild

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4267:5                   rebuild

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4553:5                   [_firstBuild]

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4737:11                  [_firstBuild]

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4548:5                   mount

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3611:13                  inflateWidget

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3363:18                  updateChild

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4599:16                  performRebuild

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4267:5                   rebuild

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4553:5                   [_firstBuild]

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4548:5                   mount

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3611:13                  inflateWidget

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3363:18                  updateChild

packages/flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart 1241:37                     updateChild

packages/flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart 1226:20                     

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 2535:19                  buildScope

packages/flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart 1219:5                      createChild

packages/flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart 349:23  

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1889:59                   

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 912:15                    [_enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees]

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1889:7                    invokeLayoutCallback

packages/flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart 338:5   [_createOrObtainChild]

packages/flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart 422:5   addInitialChild

packages/flutter/src/rendering/sliver_grid.dart 618:12               performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart 137:5             performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart 371:11            performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart 510:12                  layoutChildSequence

packages/flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart 1574:12                 [_attemptLayout]

packages/flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart 1483:20                 performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart 545:11              performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart 233:5                performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart 54:10              layoutChild

packages/flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart 896:45                      [_computeSizes]

packages/flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart 931:32                      performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart 171:10             layoutChild

packages/flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart 937:7                    performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart 240:7              [_callPerformLayout]

packages/flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart 404:14             performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 1369:11                performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 3370:13                performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart 743:14                     performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

Assertion failed: /libnavigator.dart:4564:12
!_debugLocked
is not true

Assertion failed: /libnavigator.dart:4564:12
!_debugLocked
is not true

Assertion failed: /libnavigator.dart:4564:12
!_debugLocked
is not true

Assertion failed: /libnavigator.dart:4564:12
!_debugLocked
is not true

Assertion failed: /libnavigator.dart:4564:12
!_debugLocked
is not true

Assertion failed: /libnavigator.dart:3018:18
!navigator._debugLocked
is not true

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                    layout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/view.dart 153:7                       performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1636:7                    [_layoutWithoutResize]

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 881:17                    flushLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 462:19                   drawFrame

packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 876:13                     drawFrame

packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 328:5                    [_handlePersistentFrameCallback]

packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1144:15                  [_invokeFrameCallback]

packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1082:9                   handleDrawFrame

packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 865:7                    

dart:sdk_internal 25312:11                                           internalCallback


════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///home/builder/hotbuilder/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4564:12

Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///home/builder/hotbuilder/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4564:12

Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///home/builder/hotbuilder/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4564:12

Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///home/builder/hotbuilder/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4564:12

Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///home/builder/hotbuilder/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4564:12

Assertion failed: /libnavigator.dart:3018:18
!navigator._debugLocked
is not true

No branch
```

Comment: Welcome! Please edit to 1) remove all of the duplicate messages, both before and after your code - this gives the appearance that you added extra text to bypass quality-check rules, and 2) provide more specific details (including any additional information about the exception itself). Currently you've included one small snippet of code, without line numbers, and it's impossible to know what the assertion is referring to (as we have no visibility into what's on line 4564). You need to provide as much detail as possible for others to help you.

Comment: So... I see you edited your question, but... the edit doesn't really help: you just added more exception output. There's just no possible way of knowing what code is generating this error. You have some descriptive detail in your initial error output that seems to be telling you about what to call or not call, and also line numbers. Again, this isn't correlated to anything in your question, as there is no way to see what is at any given line. Please take the time to clean up your question, remove all unnecessary detail, and focus on anything that is concrete and tangible to share.

Answer (score 0):

Review the Container, SizedBox, Column, and Row or if you implemented any card or widget...

key focus to solve:

1. size of container or sizebox
2. if you are using singlechildscrollview and inside this you have written Row() or column()   avoid using spacer() in this case and avoid making mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly()

perhaps this may help you..
still if you have problem, let me know

Answer (score -1):

#### There is more information you can give us.

---

#### Let's look closely at this

`file:///home/builder/hotbuilder/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4564:12`

On the end of this URL, you see `navigator.dart:4564:12`. Which means on line 4564 of navigator.dart, an `assert` function was called with `false`. Asserts are things we always want to be `true`, otherwise our program will misbehave. You can write your own asserts to guard your code.

Here is an example of the kind of code that is stopping you:

```dart
a = 2;
b = 3;
assert(a != 0, "You were going to divide by zero!");
print(b/a);
```

The `assert` function sometimes has a second argument, which is an explanation of the problem, but it always has a condition that must evaluate to `true`. If the condition (in our example `a != 0` is the condition) evaluates to `false` an `AssertionError` is thrown.

In our example, if we set `a` to `0`, the message would look like: `example.dart:3:0` because the assertion was on line 3.

---

#### So, what is the condition you are failing?

Comment: A comment, requesting more detail from whatever is on line 4564, would suffice. Posting an answer asking for more details... isn't really an answer. Also, you're adding code as an example that doesn't exist in the OP's code.

Comment: thanks for reply. but i am new to programming. so i cannot understand exactly what you said. and i updated my question. look at and tell solution if any. thank you.